# Watson Assistant Dialog - unable to enter into child node

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-assistant

We have configured Dialog in Watson Assistant. In that 1 Parent, 4 child is available. Inside child 3 sub-child is available.

We have configured everything sequentially and we can see the output in Tryout chat window in IBM Cloud from Parent node to sub-child node sequentially.

But for a particular input text, it is not entering into sub-child of Child node of Dialog what we configured when we tried with Android/Python. Instead it is going to Parent root node.

Kindly help us to find the root cause of this problem.

1) IBM Configuration Issue
2) Android - Java coding issue / Python coding issue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not returning the context. When your app makes a request to Watson Assistant a new context is part of the response. That content of that context object needs to be passed back to Watson Assistant. The reason is that it is stateless and everything is taken from the data that is passed around.